# If $|z^2 + z + 1| = 1$ then show that $|z|\le2$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> If $|z^2 + z + 1| = 1$ then show that $|z| \le 2$.

I know $|a| + |b| \ge |a + b|$, so $|z|^2 + |z| + 1 \ge |z^2 + z + 1| = 1$ but this isn't helping.

Comment: @ThePhoenix can you please explain a bit more? Are you trying to do it by contradiction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$|z^2|-|z|-1\le |z^2|-|z+1|\le|z^2+z+1|=1 $$

$$\begin{align}&\Rightarrow |z^2|-|z|-2\le0\\
\\
&\Rightarrow (|z|-2)\cdot(|z|+1)\le0\\
\\
&\Rightarrow (|z|-2)\le0\\
\\
&\Rightarrow |z|\le2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

Note that $z^2+z+1=\left(z+\frac 1 2\right)^2+\frac 3 4$, by triangle inequality
$$ 1=\left | z^2+z+1 \right | \geqslant \left|z+\frac 1 2\right|^2-\frac{3}{4}, $$
namely $\left|z+\frac 1 2\right|^2\leqslant \frac 7 4<\frac 9 4$. Therefore $\left | z+\frac 1 2 \right | <\frac 3 2$. Again by triangle inequality, $\left | z \right |-\frac{1}{2} \leqslant  \left | z+\frac 1 2 \right | <\frac 3 2$.

Comment: Does this mean the actual upper bound for $|z|$ is $\frac{\sqrt7 + 1}2$?

Comment: @Shub It is indeed a lower/better upper bound than $2$, though it's still not the lowest/best upper bound, see the edit at the end of my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4693919/291201).

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying by $|z-1|$ and using the difference of cubes identity and triangle inequalities:

$$
|z|^3 - 1 \le |z^3-1|=|z-1| \le |z| + 1 \quad\implies\quad |z|^3 - |z| - 2 \le 0
$$

The cubic $p(t)=t^3-t-2$ has a single real root and $p(2) \gt 0$, so the root $t_0 \lt 2$, then $|z| \le t_0 \lt 2$. In fact $t_0 \approx 1.521379\ldots$ per [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%5E3+-+z+-+2), so the stronger inequality holds $|z| \lt 1.52138$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] The upper bound derived here is lower than the upper bound  $\frac{\sqrt{7}+1}{2} \approx 1.82$ proved in another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4693662/291201), which is in turn lower than the bound of $2$ proposed in the problem. However, this is still not the *lowest* upper bound. Per [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=maximize+sqrt%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%29+when+%28x%5E2+-+y%5E2+%2B+x+%2B+1%29%5E2+%2B+%282xy+%2B+y%29%5E2+%3D+1) the best upper bound is $|z| \le \sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}} \approx 1.47$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the lowest upper bound :) Any way to find it (that a high schooler might understand)?

Comment: @Shub Actually, yes, I just posted another answer proving the lowest upper bound. I'll leave this one here, since it's more lightweight for the looser bound, but the other one is well within high-school level, too.

Answer (score 1):

(*Posted as a separate answer, since it's a very different approach, with a stronger conclusion*.)

Let $|z|^2 = z \bar z = a \ge 0$, $2 \operatorname{Re}(z) = z + \bar z = b$, then $z^2 + \bar z^2 = (z+\bar z)^2 - 2 z \bar z = b^2 - 2a$, and:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
0 = |z^2+z+1|^2 - 1 &= (z^2+z+1)(\bar z^2+\bar z+1) - 1
\\ &=z^2 \bar z^2 + z\bar z(z + \bar z)  + z^2 + \bar z^2 + z \bar z + z + \bar z + \cancel{1} - \cancel{1}
\\ &= a^2 + ab + (b^2 - 2a) + a + b
\\ &= b^2 + (a+1)b + a^2 - a
\end{align}
$$

The latter is a quadratic in $b = 2\operatorname{Re}(z) \in \mathbb R$ which must have real roots. The condition for that to happen is for its discriminant to be non-negative:

$$
\begin{align}
0 \le \Delta &= (a+1)^2 - 4(a^2 - a)
\\ &= - 3 a^2 + 6a + 1
\\ &= -3(a-1)^2  + 4
\\ \iff\qquad\;\;\; (a-1)^2 &\le\frac{4}{3}
\\ \iff\quad 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \le a &\le 1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
$$

The second inequality gives $|z|^2 = a  \le 1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \iff |z| \le \sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}} \approx 1.47 \lt 2$.

This is the lowest/best upper bound for $|z|$ since it is in fact attained for $a = 1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ $\implies b = -1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ $\implies z = \frac{b}{2} \pm i \sqrt{a - \left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2}$ $=-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} \pm i \,\sqrt{\frac{4 + 3 \sqrt{3}}{6}}\,$ (as verified in [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=maximize+sqrt%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%29+when+%28x%5E2+-+y%5E2+%2B+x+%2B+1%29%5E2+%2B+%282xy+%2B+y%29%5E2+%3D+1)).

Comment: Thanks, I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$|z^2 + z + 1| = 1 \iff z^2 + z + 1-e^{i\theta}=0$$

therefore

$$z=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{4e^{i\theta}-3}}{2} \implies z+\frac12=\pm\frac{\sqrt{4e^{i\theta}-3}}{2}$$

and then

$$\left| z+\frac12 \right|^2=\frac{\sqrt{25-24\cos\theta}}{4}\le \frac{7}4\implies |z|\le \frac{1+\sqrt 7}{2}\approx 1.823$$